# withNavigation can only be used on a view hierarchy of a navigator

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

I'm getting the error:

> Invariant Violation: withNavigation can only be used on a view
>   hierarchy of a navigator. The wrapped component is unable to get
>   access to navigation from props or context

I don't know why, because I'm using `withNavigation` in other components in my app and it works. I don't see a difference in the components that it works on to the one that causes the error.

Code:

the component:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: State): Object => ({
  alertModal: state.formControls.alertModal
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<*>): Object => {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      updateAlertModalHeight: updateAlertModalHeight,
      updateAlertModalIsOpen: updateAlertModalIsOpen,
      updateHasYesNo: updateAlertModalHasYesNo
    },
    dispatch
  )
}

class AlertModalView extends Component<AlertModalProps, State> {
  render(): Node {
    return (
      <View style={alertModalStyle.container}>
        <PresentationalModal
          style={presentationalModalStyle}
          isOpen={this.props.alertModal.isOpen}
          title={this.props.alertModal.title}
          navigation={this.props.navigation}
          updateHasYesNo={this.props.updateHasYesNo}
          message={this.props.alertModal.message}
          updateAlertModalHeight={this.props.updateAlertModalHeight}
          viewHeight={this.props.alertModal.viewHeight}
          hasYesNo={this.props.alertModal.hasYesNo}
          yesClicked={this.props.alertModal.yesClicked}
          updateAlertModalIsOpen={this.props.updateAlertModalIsOpen}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

// $FlowFixMe
const AlertModalViewComponent = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(AlertModalView)

export default withNavigation(AlertModalViewComponent)
```

the stackNavigator:

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons'
import Add from '../product/add/view'
import Login from '../user/login/view'
import Search from '../product/search/query/view'
import { Image } from 'react-native'
import { StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator, DrawerItems } from 'react-navigation'

const AddMenuIcon = ({ navigate }) => (
  <View>
    <Icon
      name="plus"
      size={30}
      color="#FFF"
      onPress={() => navigate('DrawerOpen')}
    />
  </View>
)

const SearchMenuIcon = ({ navigate }) => (
  <Icon
    name="search"
    size={30}
    color="#FFF"
    onPress={() => navigate('DrawerOpen')}
  />
)

const Stack = {
  Login: {
    screen: Login
  },
  Search: {
    screen: Search
  },
  Add: {
    screen: Add
  }
}


const DrawerRoutes = {
  Login: {
    name: 'Login',
    screen: Login
  },
  'Search Vegan': {
    name: 'Search',
    screen: StackNavigator(Stack.Search, {
      headerMode: 'none'
    }),
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      drawerIcon: SearchMenuIcon(navigation)
    })
  },
  'Add vegan': {
    name: 'Add',
    screen: StackNavigator(Stack.Add, {
      headerMode: 'none'
    }),
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      drawerIcon: AddMenuIcon(navigation)
    })
  }
}

const CustomDrawerContentComponent = props => (
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#3f3f3f', color: 'white' }}>
    <View>
      <Image
        style={{
          marginLeft: 20,
          marginBottom: 0,
          marginTop: 0,
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          resizeMode: 'contain'
        }}
        square
        source={require('../../images/logo_v_white.png')}
      />
    </View>
    <DrawerItems {...props} />
  </SafeAreaView>
)

const Menu = StackNavigator(
    {
      Drawer: {
        name: 'Drawer',
        screen: DrawerNavigator(DrawerRoutes, {
          initialRouteName: 'Login',
          drawerPosition: 'left',
          contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,
          contentOptions: {
            activeTintColor: '#27a562',
            inactiveTintColor: 'white',
            activeBackgroundColor: '#3a3a3a'
          }
        })
      }
    },
    {
      headerMode: 'none',
      initialRouteName: 'Drawer'
    }
  )


export default Menu
```

Here I render the `StackNavigator` which is `Menu` in my app component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Menu from './menu/view'
import Props from 'prop-types'
import { Container } from 'native-base'
import { updateAlertModalIsOpen } from './formControls/alertModal/action'
import AlertModalComponent from './formControls/alertModal/view'
import UserLoginModal from './user/login/loginModal/view'

class Vepo extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { store } = this.context
    this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {})
    store.dispatch(this.props.fetchUserGeoCoords())
    store.dispatch(this.props.fetchSearchQueryPageCategories())
    store.dispatch(this.props.fetchCategories())
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe()
  }

  render(): Object {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Menu store={this.context} />
        <AlertModalComponent
          yesClicked={() => {
            updateAlertModalIsOpen(false)
          }}
        />

        <UserLoginModal />
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
Vepo.contextTypes = {
  store: Props.object
}

export default Vepo
```

and my root component:

```
export const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  vepo,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic)))
)

import NavigationService from './navigationService'

export const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
      <Vepo
        fetchUserGeoCoords={fetchUserGeoCoords}
        fetchSearchQueryPageCategories={fetchSearchQueryPageCategories}
        fetchCategories={fetchCategories}
      />
  </Provider>
)
AppRegistry.registerComponent('vepo', () => App)
```

I have changed my Vepo component to this to implement the answer by vahissan:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Menu from './menu/view'
import Props from 'prop-types'
import { Container } from 'native-base'
import { updateAlertModalIsOpen } from './formControls/alertModal/action'
import AlertModalComponent from './formControls/alertModal/view'
import UserLoginModal from './user/login/loginModal/view'

import NavigationService from './navigationService'

class Vepo extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { store } = this.context
    this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {})
    store.dispatch(this.props.fetchUserGeoCoords())
    store.dispatch(this.props.fetchSearchQueryPageCategories())
    store.dispatch(this.props.fetchCategories())
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe()
  }

  render(): Object {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Menu
          store={this.context}
          ref={navigatorRef => {
            NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef)
          }}>
          <AlertModalComponent
            yesClicked={() => {
              updateAlertModalIsOpen(false)
            }}
          />
        </Menu>
        <UserLoginModal />
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
Vepo.contextTypes = {
  store: Props.object
}

export default Vepo
```

No errors, but the alertModal no longer displays

Comment: Where do you render your component wrt the StackNavigator?

Comment: @vahissan I have just posted it to the bottom of the question. Cheers

Comment: StackNavigator and your component are at the same level. That's why you got the error. You can use the withNavigation function only in components rendered in the child components of you StackNavigator.

Comment: This will help you achieve what you want https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In react-navigation, the main StackNavigator creates a context provider and the `navigation` prop will be made available to any component below its level in the component tree if they use the context consumer.

Two ways to access the `navigation` prop using context consumer is to either add the component to the StackNavigator, or use the `withNavigation` function. However because of how React's context API works, any component that uses `withNavigation` function must be below the StackNavigator in the component tree.

If you still want to access the `navigation` prop regardless of the position in component tree, you will have to store the ref to the StackNavigator in a module. Following guide from react-navigation will help you do that https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html

Comment: Thanks. This has given me the correct path to take. My app stops rendering any screens when I introduce the navigation service. I must not be doing it right. How will that fit in with my root component? I have just added my true root component to the question.

Comment: I've added my attempt to the bottom of the question

Answer (score 5):

If you are using react-navigation version 5, use useNavigation hook with a functional component. This hook injects the navigation object into the functional component. Here is the link to the docs:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. Was heavily searching for this.

Comment: Thank you! Despite having a class component as a deeply nested child of my one of my StackNavigator screens (per @vahissan's suggestion), I could not get past this error using `withNavigation`. I changed my class component to a functional component, and used the `useNavigation` hook with no issues. Did not have to move anything around in my component tree.

Answer (score 0):

Vahissan's answer is correct but I could not get it working because of various differences in my code from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html like my stackNavigator not being a component, it is just an object.

What I managed to do was get the `AlertModal` component to be a child of the stackNavigator and thus receive the `navigation` prop by adding it to my `StackNavigator`'s ContentComponent. The code is as above but int the `CustomDrawerContentComponent` just making it like this:

```
const CustomDrawerContentComponent = props => (
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#3f3f3f', color: 'white' }}>
    <View>
      <Image
        style={{
          marginLeft: 20,
          marginBottom: 0,
          marginTop: 0,
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          resizeMode: 'contain'
        }}
        square
        source={require('../../images/logo_v_white.png')}
      />
    </View>
    <DrawerItems {...props} />

    <AlertModalComponent
          yesClicked={() => {
            updateAlertModalIsOpen(false)
          }}
        />
  </SafeAreaView>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might be interested, you need to npm install @react-navigation/native @react-navigation/compat @react-navigation/stack for withNavigation to work in the recent version